# python uiautomator TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable

Tags: python, android-uiautomator

[image: Main Screen]

[image: Settings click]

Above are the uiautomator object viewer screenshots with properties. I am using python package uiautomator installed through `pip install uiautomator`. I am trying to access the three-dotted settings button through UI automator objects. I have tried using the documentation listed at https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator#handler

Here is the code and error:

```
import uiautomator as uia
d = uia.device() #below all are my attempts
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/three_dots").clickable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle").clickable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="id/mode_options_toggle")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle").clickable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle").clickable()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle", className="com.android.camera2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle", className="com.android.camera2").clcik()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle", className="com.android.camera2").click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle", className="com.android.camera2").click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(package="com.android.camera2")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/progress_overlay")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/progress_overlay")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/progress_overlay")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className="android.view.View")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className="android.view.View").child(className="android.widget.LinearLayout", resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className="android.view.View").child(className="android.widget.LinearLayout", resourceId="com.android.camera2:id/mode_options_toggle").click()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(text="").info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d.info
{u'contentDescription': u'', u'checked': False, u'clickable': False, u'scrollable': False, u'text': u'', u'packageName': u'com.android.camera2', u'selected': False, u'enabled': True, u'bounds': {u'top': 0, u'left': 0, u'right': 1440, u'bottom': 2560}, u'className': u'android.widget.FrameLayout', u'focusable': False, u'focused': False, u'checkable': False, u'resourceName': None, u'longClickable': False, u'visibleBounds': {u'top': 0, u'left': 0, u'right': 1440, u'bottom': 2392}, u'childCount': 2}
>>> d(packageName=u'com.android.camera2).info
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    d(packageName=u'com.android.camera2).info
                                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> d(packageName=u'com.android.camera2').info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className=u'com.android.camera2').info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className=u'com.android.camera2').info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className=u'').info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className=u'android.widget.FrameLayout').info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>> d(className="android.widget.FrameLayout").info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'AutomatorDeviceObject' object is not callable
>>>
```

After all attempts, I am still not able to access the any of the UI objects. Please let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: @Xiaocong can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
import uiautomator as uia
d = uia.device()
```

To:

```
import uiautomator as uia
d = uia.device
```

This should solve your problem.

It is happening because you're calling the function device() inside a variable. So "d" is not a function, but use a function to receive a value.

When we call a function using parenthesis Python understands we are calling it and using this result on your variable "d". That's the reason why you're facing "object is not callable", because no object is being passed as parameter to "device()".

When we don't use parenthesis we not call the function, we make a reference to it and the parameters will be passed when we call it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was under the assumption that I will get the device handle after calling device function. Thanks for clarifying that device handle exists in `device` variable as soon as `uiautomator` is imported. Thank you @nkborba

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to your problem but an alternative: using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) you can run

```
culebra -uG -o camera-options.py
```

once you have the window you can click on the *options* dots

[image]

see the result immediately

[image]

and at the same time, the script containing the code to reproduce this action will be generated

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2017  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2017-11-24 by Culebra v13.5.2
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

TAG = 'CULEBRA'

_s = 5
_v = '--verbose' in sys.argv


kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)
#vc.dump(window='-1') # FIXME: seems not needed

vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithContentDescriptionOrRaise(u'''Options''').touch()
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the new tool, but I was looking for the help on `uiautomator` python module only. Upvoting the nice tool